# Unlcear about noise making as a useful tactical move

Tags: zombicide, zombicide-black-plague

One of the actions one can take is to make noise. This adds one noise token to one's current location. In addition, as far as I understand the rules, each character makes a noise automatically.

This means that making a noise is only useful in a very narrow set of circumstances: zombies have no line of sight, there is no big group of characters, and no other noise around (breaking doors, some spells, etc...)

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the cases where I've used the noise making tactic:

1. **To avoid splitting**. If a group of zombies has 2 equally noisy target zones to move to, and you want to avoid adding extra zombies due to splitting (i.e. an odd number of zombies in the starting zone), then making noise clarifies the target zone
2. **As a lure**. For example, luring zombies onto a dragon fire trap, luring a group of zombies away from a necromancer who is about to escape, luring a group of zombies into a room to trap them using the lock it down skill etc.
3. **To use towers more effectively**. Towers (in the Wulfsberg expansion), allow for archers and spell casters to have more safe shots at zombies. It may be useful to lure zombies towards the tower (to get more shots) or away from the tower (to allow a survivor to escape the tower)
4. **To allow a survivor to escape**. Particularly useful when a survivor is in a dead end, or you want zombies to head towards survivors with armour/ironclad skills/regenerate etc.